# How do I return an IEnumerable<> using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

I've been using Dapper and with my current project I'm going to have to use ADO.NET. My question is how do I return an IEnumerable using ADO.NET? Here is what I have using Dapper. Can someone help me with converting this to do the same but with ADO?

```
public IEnumerable<Favorites> GetFavorites()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var work = sqlConnection.Query<Favorites>("Select * from favorites");
        return work;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you happy working with DataSets and DataRows for your entities (e.g. Favourites) or do you need strongly-typed classes?

Comment: Standard ADO.NET functionality isn't going to map the data results to an object for you.  You'd essentially get back a `DataSet` from the query and would have to build your `Favorites` objects from that.

Comment: Just iterate through the `DataSet` rows, `yield`ing a new `Favorite` object for each one

Comment: Otherwise you can call AsEnumerable() on your DataTable to return an IEnumerable<DataRow>.

Comment: @paul ADO.NET does not necessarily mean "DataSet". That is a layer *on top of* ADO.NET

Comment: Just saying... dapper *entirely uses* ADO.NET. You could just bring the **single .cs file** (SqlMapper.cs IIRC) into your project, call it "MyUsefulUtility.cs" instead of "dapper". I won't mind, and we won't tell anyone ;p

Comment: What's wrong with usage of Dapper? You want to do same thing, but manually?

Comment: Got to love SO... You just asked how you can emulate Dapper in your ADO.net project. And one of the authors (@MarcGravell) of Dapper just told you which .cs file to grab and rename to emulate it in your project. One word, Awesome!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `yield return` like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Favorites> GetFavorites()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from favorites";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Create a Favorites instance
                    var favorites = new Favorites();
                    favorites.Foo = reader["foo"];
                    // ... etc ...
                    yield return favorites;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can refactor this by creating a Favorites constructor that accepts an `IDataReader` or `SqlDataReader`, or creating a utility method to populate the values, or whatever, but this is the basic structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do you work all within the `using` block, you can take advantage of LINQ and the `IEnumerable` interface on `DbDataReader`. It provides self-contained pure ADO.NET with a reasonably small amount of code.

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from favorites";
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    var work = from IDataRecord r in select ...;
    ... use work ...
}
```